# PNG image "on-click" animation with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create "custom button" using PNG image that will have three "states":

1. Standard idle image (green_button.png)
2. On-hover image (green_button_hover.png)
3. On-click animation (6 frames)

I found out that the gif animation cannot be easily displayed in Tkinter, so I decided for "custom solution" - divide the button animation into 6 different frames (PNG images - from green_button_click_0.png to green_button_click_5.png) and display it one by one with some time delay. Unfortunately it is not working, I tried many variants and nothing seems to solve the issue. The only thing I learned is that I cannot use the `time.sleep()` for waiting between the frames since it will freeze the app and not display anything.

The hovering (`<Enter>` and `<Leave>`) works OK, but the animation does nothing on click. Can somebody give me some advice please?

Here is the excerpt of my code (I am a total Python beginner so it is probably full of nonsenses, sorry about that):

```
# Green button definition:
    green_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "images/buttons/green_button.png")
    self.PlayerCanvas.create_image(green_button_x, green_button_y, image = green_button_image, tags = ('green_hover'))
    self.PlayerCanvas.image = green_button_image
    self.PlayerCanvas.tag_bind('green_hover', '<Enter>', self.green_hover)


def green_hover(self, event):
    green_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = 'images/buttons/green_button_hover.png')
    self.PlayerCanvas.create_image(green_button_x, green_button_y, image = green_button_image, tags = ('green_leave', 'green_click'))
    self.PlayerCanvas.image = green_button_image
    self.PlayerCanvas.tag_bind('green_leave', '<Leave>', self.green_leave)
    self.PlayerCanvas.tag_bind('green_click', '<Button-1>', self.green_click)

def green_leave(self, event):
    green_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = 'images/buttons/green_button.png')
    self.PlayerCanvas.create_image(green_button_x, green_button_y, image = green_button_image, tags = 'green_hover')
    self.PlayerCanvas.image = green_button_image

def green_click(self, event):
    frames = 5
    frame = 0
    while frame <= frames:
        self.green_animation(frame, frames)
        frame += 1
    else:
        green_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = 'images/buttons/green_button.png')
        self.PlayerCanvas.create_image(green_button_x, green_button_y, image = green_button_image, tags = 'green_hover')
        self.PlayerCanvas.image = green_button_image

def green_animation(self, frame, frames):
    green_button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = 'images/buttons/green_button_click_' + str(frame) + '.png')
    self.PlayerCanvas.create_image(green_button_x, green_button_y, image = green_button_image)
    self.PlayerCanvas.image = green_button_image
```

Comment: You can use the universal widget [`after()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method instead of `time.sleep()` in tkinter applications.

Comment: @martineau I already tried it by adding the line:
`my_window.after(1000, self.green_animation(frame, frames))`
at the end of `green_animation`. It displayed many, many errors unfortunately, so I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not enough code in you question (nor comment) for me to even guess what went wrong with whatever it was that you tried.

Comment: The "on-click" animation part in the code excerpt must be wrong, with or without the time delay, I guess. I can include the whole code, but it probably wont help since this is really the only part involving the "green button" functionality, so I though maybe it will be obvious that my approach is completely wrong, that is what I am trying to find out - how to make it work (as described above). But thanks anyway!

Comment: Offhand it seems like one might be able to animate the image displayed on a `Button` by using the `after()` method to repeatedly schedule a call to a function that would display successive frames of the animation. You can change the image displayed on a button by using its `config(image=a_photo_image)` method.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but if I am not mistaken the `Button` nor `Label` cannot have transparent background in PNG image. I forgot to mention that above, but this seems unfortunately the only way to do it (using `.create_image` in Canvas).

Comment: Correct, as far as I know, tkinter doesn't support images with transparcy on its widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can use `.after(<delay in ms>, <callback>, *args for the callback)` to repeatedly change the image you use as a button. It is an item on a canvas, so it can be changed using

```
canvas.itemconfigure(<item id or tag>, image=<new image>)
```

On click, launch the animation `self.green_animation(0)`, which is done as follows:

```
def green_animation(self, index):
    self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.green_button, image=self.anim[index])
    if index < len(self.anim) - 1: # it is not the last image, schedule next image change
        self.after(1000, self.green_animation, index + 1)
```

In the end I did something a bit more complex to avoid clashes between enter/leave  and click animation and when re-clicking on the button before the end of the animation:

- I used the boolean `self.anim_on` to know whether the animation is running and prevent the enter/leave appearance change if it is the case.
- I stored the id of the schedule callback in `self.anim_after_id` to cancel it if the user re-clicks on the button so as to avoid running the animation twice simultaneously.

Here is a full example, changing the button color instead of the image so that it can be easily run by anyone:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.green_button = self.canvas.create_oval(50, 50, 100, 100, fill='green', tags='button') # button
        self.anim = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'cyan', 'blue', 'green']  # replace image sequence by colors for the example
        self.anim_on = False
        self.anim_after_id = None

        self.canvas.tag_bind('button', '<Enter>', self.green_enter)
        self.canvas.tag_bind('button', '<Leave>', self.green_leave)
        self.canvas.tag_bind('button', '<ButtonRelease-1>', self.green_click)

    def green_enter(self, event):
        if self.anim_on:
            return
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.green_button, fill='light green')

    def green_leave(self, event):
        if self.anim_on:
            return
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.green_button, fill='green')

    def green_click(self, event):
        # cancel previous anim if running
        try:
            self.after_cancel(self.anim_after_id)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        self.anim_on = True
        self.green_animation(0)

    def green_animation(self, index):
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.green_button, fill=self.anim[index])
        if index < len(self.anim) - 1:
            self.anim_after_id = self.after(1000, self.green_animation, index + 1)
        else:
            self.anim_on = False

App().mainloop()
```

To adapt it for images, just change:

- `create_oval` -> `create_image`
- `self.anim = [image1, ...]`
- `fill=...` -> `image=...`

[image: screencast]

Code with the images and without inheriting from `tk.Tk`:

```
import Tkinter as tk  #  python2
from PIL import ImageTk

class App:
    def __init__(self, the_window):
        self.window = the_window
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(the_window)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='images/buttons/green_button.png')
        self.img_hover = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='images/buttons/green_button_hover.png')

        self.green_button = self.canvas.create_image(50, 50, image=self.img, tags='button') # button
        self.anim = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='images/buttons/green_button_click_%i.png' % i) for i in range(5)]
        self.anim.append(self.img)

        self.anim_on = False
        self.anim_after_id = None

        self.canvas.tag_bind('button', '<Enter>', self.green_enter)
        self.canvas.tag_bind('button', '<Leave>', self.green_leave)
        self.canvas.tag_bind('button', '<ButtonRelease-1>', self.green_click)

    def green_enter(self, event):
        if self.anim_on:
            return
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.green_button, image=self.img_hover)

    def green_leave(self, event):
        if self.anim_on:
            return
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.green_button, image=self.img)

    def green_click(self, event):
        # cancel previous anim if running
        try:
            self.window.after_cancel(self.anim_after_id)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        self.anim_on = True
        self.green_animation(0)

    def green_animation(self, index):
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.green_button, image=self.anim[index])
        if index < len(self.anim) - 1:
            self.anim_after_id = self.window.after(1000, self.green_animation, index + 1)
        else:
            self.anim_on = False

my_window = tk.Tk()
app = App(my_window)
my_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: That is amazing, thank you very much! I replaced the colours by images as you said, and the hover works ok, but unfortunately I am still having issues with the click, it just gives me this:
 `...
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1909, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1909, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Comment: @OndřejBaše I don't know what caused your error. I have added the code using images. I've run it with python2 and it works without errors.

Comment: All right I will investigate some more, I probably made some mistake during the adding of images. Anyway thanks again for a great answer!

Comment: If anybody is having the same error as I had:
`maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`
the code just needs this line:
`tk.Tk.__init__(self)`
without it the animation will not work, no idea why. It basically just opens second window every time (I have all the widgets in another window), and then it works ok. Weird.

Comment: @OndřejBaše this is not weird, this is an OOP issue arising from merging your class with mine. You did not include your full class definition in the question but I guess it does not inherit from `tk.Tk`, but has a `Tk` instance as an attribute. Conversely my `App` class inherits from `tk.Tk` and when a class inherits from another one, you need to initialize the parent class in `__init__`.

Comment: True, my class is defined as:
`class MyGameApp():
 def __init__(self, the_window, width, height, colour, row, column):`
Then there are the widgets / elements.
The window itself is defined as "stand-alone" in the end:
`my_window = tk.Tk()
my_window.overrideredirect(True)
my_window.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
my_window.wm_attributes("-transparent", True) ... ` etc etc (some geometry, title and such) and it ends with `my_game = MyGameApp(my_window, width = w, height = h, colour = colour, row = 0, column = 0) 
my_window.mainloop()`. So how can I merge it correctly with your code pls?

Comment: @OndřejBaše I have adapted my second example to be closer to you code structure, you should now be able to merge it with your code.